# Can't watch online videos on Android 4.2.2 tablet

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, video, streaming

I have Android 4.2.2 on a CRXT 1131 tablet.

I am interested in nsfw videos but I can't play videos longer than 5 minutes. Earlier I could watch *any* video online, then some problem happened and videos stopped playing. So I did a hard reset and even now I can't see video on nsfw sites. However youtube videos in chrome browser work just fine.

How can I watch any video I like.

Comment: Since you said that the videos are NSFW, have you checked if your network provider is filtering certain web content?

Comment: Do you pay for the internet connection and the Android device or do your mom and dad buy it for you?

Answer (score 0):

firstly switch between your wifi and data if that doesn't work try using a different browser like uc browser that uses its own servers to play online content.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl&hl=en